# Using Hibernate Session.doWork for Sequence ID Generation

Tags: java, hibernate, connection, prepared-statement

Hibernate Session' [`doWork()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work)) method gives direct access to `java.sql.Connection`.

Following is one of the way to create and execute a `PreparedStatement` to generate sequence

```
public Long generateId() {
    final Long id[] = { null };

    getSessionFactory().openSession().doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT HIB_SEQ.nextval FROM DUAL");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                id[0] = rs.getLong(0);
            }
        }
    });
    return id[0];
}
```

First, is there a better way to do this ?

Second Q do we need to explicitly close the `PreparedStatement` created above ?

Answer (score 1):

An instance of `PreparedStatement` is created as part of method `Work.execute` and thus should be handled within that scope, including closing (an instance itself will be collected by GC once method finishes its execution since variable `ps` would become out of scope, but any external resources such as open cursor require an explicit call `ps.close()`).

An instance of `Connection` on the other hand is passed into the method by Hibernate and should not be closed manually -- this is Hibernate's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

1) For returning value we can use [`doReturningWork`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doReturningWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork))

```
public int updateEmployeeStatusWithCount(final List<String> employeeList) throws DBException
{
       Session session = null;
       try
       {
              session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
              session.beginTransaction();
              int cnt = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Integer>() {
                     @Override
                     public Integer execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                           PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
                           try
                           {
                                  int updatedCnt = 0;
                                  String sqlQry = "UPDATE EMP_DETAILS set IS_ACTIVE='N' WHERE EMP_ID=?";
                                  pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQry);
                                  for(String empId:employeeList)
                                  {
                                         System.out.println(empId);
                                         pStmt.setString(1, empId);
                                         int cnt = pStmt.executeUpdate();
                                         updatedCnt+=cnt;
                                  }
                                  return updatedCnt;
                           }
                           finally
                           {
                                  pStmt.close();
                           }                                
                     }
              });
              session.getTransaction().commit();
              return cnt;
       }
       catch(HibernateException e)
       {
              throw new DBException("Error occured while updating Employee Status",e);
       }
       finally
       {
              HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
       }            
}
```

2)Yes We have to explicitly close the `PreparedStatement`
See below example

```
public void updateEmployeeStatus(final List<String> employeeList) throws DBException
{
       Session session = null;
       try
       {
              session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
              session.beginTransaction();
              session.doWork(new Work() {
                     @Override
                     public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                           PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
                           try
                           {
                                  String sqlQry = "UPDATE EMP_DETAILS set IS_ACTIVE='N' WHERE EMP_ID=?";
                                  pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQry);
                                  for(String empId:employeeList)
                                  {
                                         pStmt.setString(1, empId);
                                         pStmt.addBatch();
                                  }
                                  pStmt.executeBatch();
                           }
                           finally
                           {
                                  pStmt.close();
                           }                                
                     }
              });
              session.getTransaction().commit();
       }
       catch(HibernateException e)
       {
              throw new DBException("Error occured while updating Employee Status",e);
       }
       finally
       {
              HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
       }            
}
```

[Reference](http://keyurj.blogspot.in/2012/12/dowork-in-hibernate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String query = ((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getDialect().getSequenceNextValString(seqName);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Long) session.createSQLQuery(query).addScalar("nextval", Hibernate.LONG).uniqueResult();
```

You may want to tweak the scalar part a bit to fit your database's column name and return type.